# JQuery not working, why?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to JQuery and i created a script, and a css style. I'm getting the styles to work, but not the JQuery.

I created this style:

```
tr:hover, tr.selected {
    background-color: #FFCF8B
}
```

I was following this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/KzVfy/

I want to do exactly the same on my table:

```
<table id="table-organizaciones" class="table table-fixed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-4">Nombre</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">Razon social</th>
        <th class="col-xs-4">Pais</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% List<Organizacion> organizaciones = (List<Organizacion>)session.getAttribute("organizaciones");
        Organizacion organizacion;
        for(int i=0; i<organizaciones.size(); ++i){
        organizacion = new Organizacion();
        organizacion.setDireccion(organizaciones.get(i).getDireccion());
        organizacion.setNombre(organizaciones.get(i).getNombre());              organizacion.setRazonSocial(organizaciones.get(i).getRazonSocial());
        organizacion.setRif(organizaciones.get(i).getRif());
        %>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-4"><%= organizacion.getNombre()%></td>
            <td class="col-xs-4"><%= organizacion.getRazonSocial() %></td>
            <td class="col-xs-4">Colombia</td>
        </tr>
        <%} %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

To add JQuery:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My JQuery after the body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("tr").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
    });
</script>
```

I will be really thankful i you could help me.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript"> <script type="text/javascript">` double script tags?

Comment: **and your fiddle is working fine**...

Comment: As @GuruprasadRao says, your fiddle works fine. If the code isn't working in your own environment, check the console for errors.

Comment: The fiddle you've included is the one you're working to - can you include a fiddle or code snippet of **your work**?  Here's some more info [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I fork a new jsfiddle for you.

```
$("tr").click(function(){
  $("tr").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Check this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c2yr8swm/)

Comment: Don't use this. The OP approach is even better ( this would manipulate all tr's, even if they are from different table ) ( the problem must be somewhere else.. ) ( check the developer's console errors )

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `<script> </script>` tags , don't write type="text/javascript" in between script tag. 
Do give the feedback it works or not too.

Comment: Hi. Is still not working... i'm starting to think maybe is a problem with eclipse, or i don't know, i'm kind of lost. It must be a silly problem